# my code in python is repeating itself for unknown reason

Tags: python

Please, help me to figure out what's wrong with this code (which is just a piece of a larger one) as I can't understand why it repeats itself.

```py
def function():
    username = input('username: ')
    password = input('password: ')
    print('is this correct?' + username + ' ' + password)
    bool_ = input('y/n:')
    return bool_

bool__ = function()

if bool__ == 'n':
    username = input('new username:  ')
    password = input('new password:  ')

input_ = input(' 1. create account \n2. log in')
if input_ == 1:
    function()
```

Comment: Do you have return output?  What exactly is being repeated?

Comment: well you have `function()` down there in the bottom for some reason, so yea

Comment: I just ran your code, and it works fine for me. You should post the minimum reproducible code so we can replicate your error.

Comment: `if input_ == 1:` will never succeed, since `input_` is a string, while `1` is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
username = input('username: ')
password = input('password: ')
print('is this correct?' + username + ' ' + password)

def function():
    print('is this correct?' + username + ' ' + password)
    bool_ = input('y/n:')
    return bool_

bool__ = 'n'

while bool__ != 'y':
    username = input('new username:  ')
    password = input('new password:  ')
    bool__ = function()

input_ = input(' 1. create account \n2. log in ')
if input_ == 1:
    function()
```

I am not sure this does what you are looking for, but its response looks at least reasonable